# Perform additional operations for each call to an external API

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have an external API that I cannot modify. For each call to this API, I need to be able to perform an operation before and after. This API is used like this:

```
def get_api():
    """
    Return an initiated ClassAPI object
    """
    token = Token.objects.last()
    api = ClassAPI(
        settings.CLASS_API_ID,
        settings.CLASS_API_SECRET,
        last_token)

    return api
```

`get_api()` is called everywhere in the code and the result is then used to perform request (like: `api.book_store.get(id=book_id)`).
My goal is to return a virtual object that will perform the same operations than the `ClassAPI` adding print "Before" and print "After".

The `ClassAPI` looks like this:

```
class ClassAPI
    class BookStore
        def get(...)
        def list(...)

    class PenStore
        def get(...)
        def list(...)
```

I tried to create a class inheriting from `(ClassApi, object)` [as `ClassAPI` doesn't inherit from `object`] and add to this class a metaclass that decorates all the methods, but I cannot impact the methods from `BookStore` (get and list)

Any idea about how to perform this modifying only `get_api()` and adding additional classes? I try to avoid copying the whole structure of the API to add my operations.

I am using python 2.7.

Comment: How does ClassAPI create `book_store` (and presumably `pen_store`)?

Comment: The ClassAPI constains the book_store in its attributes:
`class ClassAPI:
    def __init__(self,client_id,client_secret,access_token):
        self.credential_manager = CredentialManager(client_id,client_secret,access_token)
        self.book_store = BookStore(self.credential_manager)
        self.pen_store = PenStore(self.credential_manager)
        self.reviews_store = ReviewStore(self.credential_manager)
        self.booking_store = BookingStore(self.credential_manager)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a Proxy:

```
class Proxy:
    def __init__(self, other):
        self.other = other
        self.calls = []

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        self.calls.append(name)
        return self

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.before()
        ret = self.call_proxied(*args, **kwargs)
        self.after()
        return ret

    def call_proxied(self, *args, **kwargs):
        other = self.other
        calls = self.calls
        self.calls = []
        for item in calls:
            other = getattr(other, item)
        return other(*args, **kwargs)
```

This class intercepts unknown members in the `__getattr__()` method, saving the names that are used and returning itself.

When a method is called (eg. `api.book_store.get(id=book_id)` ), it calls a `before()` and `after()` method on itself and in between it fetches the members of `other` and forwards the arguments in a call.

You use this class like this:

```
def get_api():
    ...
    return Proxy(api)
```

**Update:** corrected the call to `self.call_proxied(*args, **kwargs)`. Also allow any return value to be returned.

Comment: Thank you for your answer quamrana. I didn't saw this lead previously, I am checking now how proxies work. The current example goes in too deep recursion, even without self.before() & self.after(), but I am checking how to modify this to make it works.

Comment: I tested it with some modifications. I removed self.calls=[]. I have an issue with *args and **kwargs that are a bit mixed. I try the following:         proxy_api.booking_store.get(id=booking_id) and I get the error: TypeError: get() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
The chain is properly iterated and I reach the right method inside the right object. At the end, I have: args = ((), {'id': '2830000'}), kwargs={}. I think that this is not expected: id should be in kwargs, no ?

Comment: Note that the for loop is: `for item in calls:` and the call is `other(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Yes, I used the following:         for item in calls:
            other = getattr(other, item)

        other(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: It seems ok with         self.call_proxied(*args, **kwargs). I test it a bit more to confirm that everything is working fine. Thank you very much !

Comment: I forgot to add a return at the end of the proxy method. will update soon.